# WhatsApp preview for shared link sometimes work for some countries and IP and sometimes doesn't work for other countries or IP

Tags: whatsapp

The preview for a given link like the -  [One](https://www.iqiglobal.com/agent/hanafiah)
sometimes works for some countries and IPs sometimes do not, especially once the country or IP changes.
Any suggestion or recommendation to resolve the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure how the mechanism works, but since WhatsApp is end-to-end encrypted, it could well be that the individual devices make the request to fetch the relevant meta data. So I would go check if you have any access restrictions set up for your site there. Checking the access and error logs around a time when it just went wrong, might also bring up some additional details.